# error to save xml

Tags: xml, xml-serialization, xsd, linq-to-xml

When I call:

```
doc1.Save("C:\\Users\\Mansour\\Documents\\Visual Studio
  2008\\WebSites\\WebSite1\\Web.sitemap");
```

I get the following error. What does this error mean?

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Mansour\Documents\Visual Studio 2008
  \WebSites\WebSite1\Web.sitemap' because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that another program has the file open and is locking it.  You can use a tool like FileMon to tell you what program is causing the problem.